# Liferay: Language keys override for portlet without webcontext

Tags: java, internationalization, liferay, liferay-7.1

I am facing an odd situation here, all of Liferay docs show how to override language keys for both portlets and global keys. But following the official doc, it seems that some information is missing as for how to add/override language keys when the portlet does not have a web-context declared.

Doc I am following: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/overriding-language-keys

I successfully made modules for both scenarios: portlet and global. However, while I can do it for the knowledge base I cannot do it for the contacts portlet.

Am I missing something? Maybe a default context?

Update:

Opened an issue at: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-93737

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I cannot do it..."? E.g. please [show code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're probably right in that you miss something - but how should anyone tell what it is without seeing what you're doing?

Comment: the code is in the docs too. it is actually just metadata. the question is simple, the docs show a way to do this for modules that have a web-context, that is the only difference between KB and contacts. it is a matter of procedure missing in the docs, not code.

Comment: In that case I will need to go through all the documentation and figure out what works and what doesn't. You mention that you're successful for "portlet and global", but then you mention two portlets where it only works for one. Even if it's in the docs: Those external references might go away - to make the question valuable even for people coming along later, it'd be way better to make it self-contained and show *exactly* the code in question (MCVE).

Comment: If the official docs go away, we will have bigger issues. But the question could not be simpler: how to apply the documented procedure when there is no web context? No need to over complicate.

Comment: A stock reason to close a question as off-topic on stackoverflow reads: "Questions seeking debugging help ( **"why isn't this code working?"** ) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** ...." That includes the emphasis, I didn't add it. And be assured that the docs won't go away, they might change URLs though.

Comment: there is no code, I am looking for the procedure. It is missing in the docs.

Comment: Well, you state that you *cannot do it for the contacts portlet*. If there's no code/project/nothing involved, then here's your reason. Another stock reason for closing is "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow". Again, the emphasis is *not mine*. But anyways: I'm out. I'm not willing to go through two chapters of documentation and figure out what would be missing. If you think the documentation is missing content, please comment there.

Comment: please check: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-93737